# What should I use instead of the deprecated Date.getHours()

Tags: java, datetime, deprecated

If a method is deprecated in Java there will be a another better way to have same functionality, right?

```
Date date = new Date();
date.getHours()
```

As `getHours()` is deprecated, what is the best way to get hours using only the `Date` class?

Comment: What does the javadoc say?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be using a Calendar or the Joda Time library.

However if you can only use Date, this is your only method.  Note, this will not adjust for timezone.

Answer (score 13):

[Javadoc explicitly suggests](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getHours%28%29)

```
Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY).
```

[Joda library](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) is another best alternative to handle Date and Time.

Answer (score 12):

As others already stated [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getHours%28%29) suggests to instead use `Calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)`.

```
Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY).
```

Here's how you could do it for already set `Date`:

```
int getHourOfDay(Date date) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    return calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
}
```

Use `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` if you want number from 0-23 and `Calendar.HOUR` for 0-11.

Comment: Your answer is the only one describing how to get from an existing Date to the hour like OP asked.
Your answer should be accepted!

Answer (score 10):

These methods are indeed deprecated.

You should now use java.util.Calendar#get()

So your example becomes

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
```

see [the javadoc of this class.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

Note that you can get a Date object by calling getTime on cal.

Answer (score 6):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
```

If you want is as a date

```
Date date = cal.getTime();
```

Comment: Wrong. `Date.getHours()` tried to return the hour of day (0–23). `cal.get(Calendar.HOUR)` gives you the hour within AM or PM (0–11). Not that it matters these days. Both `Date` and `calendar` were poorly designed and are long outdated. Don’t use either of them at all. Use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

You can use [`ZonedDateTime#now(ZoneId)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#now-java.time.ZoneId-) to get the current Date-Time object from which you can get the information like timezone offset, year, month, day, **hour**, minute, second, nanosecond etc. If you do not need timezone offset, you can use [`LocalDateTime#now(ZoneId)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#now-java.time.ZoneId-) instead. However, if you need just the current time information, you can use [`LocalTime#now(ZoneId)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#now-java.time.ZoneId-) to get the local time in a specific timezone and then get **hour**, minute, second, nanosecond etc. from the `LocalTime`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Change the JVM's ZoneId, ZoneId.systemDefault() with the applicable ZoneId
        // e.g. ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles")
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault();

        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now(zoneId);
        System.out.println(zdt.getHour());

        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now(zoneId);
        System.out.println(ldt.getHour());

        LocalTime time = LocalTime.now(zoneId);
        System.out.println(time.getHour());
    }
}
```

**Output from a sample run:**

```
13
13
13
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/byjfs1)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score -1):

use such as below code.

```
Date date = new Date();
    System.out.println(date);
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("HH").format(date));
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("mm").format(date));
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("MM").format(date));
}
```

Comment: As this answer currently stands, it is hard to decipher which line of output shows the expected result without knowing or referring to the specification of `SimpleDateFormat`. Please remove the unnecessary outputs or elaborate on each line of output.